Parsing CString YYYYMMDD into COleDateTime to get SHORTDATE?
I have a date in a CString: "20240415". How can I parse this into a COleDateTime? My goal is to format this as a short date.
I tried:
COleDateTime lastInstalledDate;
if (lastInstalledDate.ParseDateTime(strInstallDate, VAR_DATEVALUEONLY, LANG_USER_DEFAULT))
{
    strInstallDate = lastInstalledDate.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);
}

But the  result was still: "20240415" instead of "15/04/2024".

According to the documentation of COleDateTime::ParseDateTime, "20240415" cannot be parsed by this function.

@Jabberwocky Ok. I’ll convert it to a long then and go from long to COleDateTime.

Or try "2024.04.15" instead of "20240415"

@Jabberwocky The former is how it is formatted in the registry.

Yep, but that format is incompatible with the ParseDateTime function.

If you know the precise format of the string and you have access to C++20 try std::chrono::parse instead. std::format can be used to turn the time point into a string, using whichever locale you want (or no locale).

@IInspectable I always struggle reading such documentation. I'd be interested in trying if I get my head around the two APIs.

The documentation is indeed near incomprehensible. Here's an example that illustrates the parsing, and this answer shows formatting.

I'd transform L"20240415" into L"2024-04-15" somehow, for example by inserting 2 hyphens and then simply use COleDateTime::Format:
    CString strInstallDate = L"20240415";

    strInstallDate.Insert(4, L'-'); strInstallDate.Insert(7, L'-');
    COleDateTime lastInstalledDate;
    lastInstalledDate.ParseDateTime(strInstallDate, VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);
    CString strFormattedInstallDate = lastInstalledDate.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);
    ...


This works:
CString strInstallDate = L"20240415";

const auto longInstallDate = _ttol(strInstallDate);
const auto nYear = longInstallDate / 10000;
const auto nMonth = (longInstallDate / 100) % 100;
const auto nDay = longInstallDate % 100;

COleDateTime datInstallDate;
datInstallDate.SetDateTime(nYear, nMonth, nDay, 0, 0, 0);

CString strFormattedInstallDate = datInstallDate.Format(VAR_DATEVALUEONLY);


This is a hack. I'd rather transform strInstallDate from L"20240415" into L"2024.04.15" by inserting 2 dots  and then simply use COleDateTime::Format. That will save you 4 lines

@Jabberwocky but it will take two lines to add the dots. No?

Not necessarily, look at my answer
